# Modifying an indexed DataFrame inside a function changes the original variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-applymap

The following script prints the same input variable `input_df` twice at the end - before and after `df_lower` has been called:

```
import pandas as pd

def df_lower(df):
    cols = ['col_1']
    df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
    return df

input_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': ['ABC'],
    'col_2': ['XYZ']
})

print(input_df)
processed_df = df_lower(input_df)
print(input_df)
```

The output shows that `input_df` changes:

```
  col_1 col_2
0   ABC   XYZ
  col_1 col_2
0   abc   XYZ
```

Why is `input_df` modified?

Why isn't it modified when full `input_df` (no column indexing) is processed?

```
def df_lower_no_indexing(df):
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
    return df
```

Comment: Because by taking the input_df into the function and using df[cols] = blabla, you are making the new variable and the old , point to the same place in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assinging to a slice of the input dataframe.
In the *no indexing* case, you are just assigning a new value to the local variable `df`:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
```

Which creates a new variable, leaving the input as is.

Conversely, in the first case, you are assigning a value to a slice of the input, hence, modifying the input itself:

```py
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
```

With a simple change, you can create a new variable as well in the first case:

```py
def df_lower(df):
    cols = ['col_1']
    df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col not in cols]]
    df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
    return df
```